# Why is my Rubbish Bin Icon in Unity Launcher opening with Gwenview?

Tags: unity, launcher

I guess the question says it all =/ Already installed Ubuntu Tweak and fiddled with the associations, but nothing is associated with Gwenview. Still, the rubbish bin opens up with it instead of nautilus. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your problem sounds similar to [this resolved question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73979/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-open-folders-with-nautilus-by-default) about folders in Nautilus opening in Movie Player by default. Perhaps your issue has a similar cause?

Comment: The solution on the provided by Warrioring64 (http://askubuntu.com/questions/73979/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-open-folders-with-nautilus-by-default) resolved the issue! Thanks a lot, man! =D

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie in this file: `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

You could back it up and then delete it. The file will be reconstituted as you open apps over time: "as you use the context menu or set new defaults the list will 'grow'".

More detailed information is in [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861067).

I had this problem when I upgraded 11.04 to 11.10 and clicking Trash in the Launcher opened Movie Player.