# Disk Usage Analyzer stealing mimetype assocation inode/directory from Nautilus

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, mime-type

So this is a fun problem. After upgrading to Raring Ringtail, the open file command for nautilus on everything except the file browser in unity itself (opening downloads from browsers, clicking on removable media in unity) opens the Disk Usage Analyzer instead of nautilus. Is there a config file somewhere that chooses these defaults? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit `/usr/share/applications/baobab.desktop` and change

```
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

with

```
MimeType=inode/directory:1;
```

then run this command:

```
sudo update-desktop-database -q
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Check: http://askubuntu.com/a/405317/110181

Comment: Anyone knows what the colon really does?

Answer (score 7):

To me it seems the appropriate way is to define Nautilus as the default application to handle the mimetype inode/directory. This can be done via console with

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

What it does is adding the following line to .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
```

[About accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/289238/233113): I don't know what adding a colon and a number to the mimetype in the baobab desktop file does, but if it's just disabling the unwanted behaviour this won't be sufficient. I can imagine another application hijacking/overriding the mimetype assocation again.

Another point is that you have all your defaults defined in one place.

Comment: Works for me. Accepted solution doesn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `/usr/share/applications/baobab.desktop` by issuing this command:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/baobab.desktop
```

And remove this line:

```
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

Then save. If that fixes your problems, please take a minute to [file a bugreport on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/baobab/+bugs).

Comment: Your suggestion will prevent baobab from advertising itself it's able to manage the inode mime type. This is not true and won't protect you from another program advertising itself being able to manage inode and _stealing_ the association again. You have to define a default or elaborate why your defined defaults won't work. See [Archlinux-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications#MIME_types_and_desktop_entries)