# Places opens in Disk Usage Analyzer in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, disk-usage, default-programs, sublime-text, mime-type

I have updated my ubuntu from 12.10 to latest **Ubuntu 13.04.** everything is fine but when i go to Places and click any place, it opens in **Disk Usage Analyzer** by default and i found no way to either stop Disk usage analyzer permanantely or to change the default Application for Places. Please tell me how to set it default so that Places opens properly.

Please see the image, I open Places > Music folder but it opens in  [image: Disk Usage Anylyzer]

I found [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288270/disk-usage-analyzer-replacing-nautilus) but the solution doesn't works for me as I do

edit **/usr/share/applications/baobab.desktop** and change

```
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

with

```
MimeType=inode/directory:1;
```

and now everything opens in **sublime-text**

**Note:** I have many changes while i was using ubuntu 12.10 , still i am using session fallback desktop theme in latest ubuntu. does that affect?

Comment: anyone for help?

Comment: [solved]: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1186209#p1186209

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on 14.04 using the gnome-session-fallback desktop. After trying the other solutions (removing `MimeType=inode/directory;` and editing `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`) what actually fixed the problem was to run this command as your user:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop  inode/directory
```

By default it is set to use `nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`, which for some reason ends up launching the dreaded baobab.

Comment: Happened again for me on 16.04, this works.

Comment: not working on 21.04

Answer (score 2):

When I went to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1186209#p1186209 I've found the solution in there.
Remove `MimeType=inode/directory;` from `/usr/share/applications/baobab.desktop` and run as root

```
update-desktop-database -q
```

Comment: not working on 21.04

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Kubuntu 17.10 and had a similar problem (in my case, it opened `git-cola`). Thanks to richq's answer I figured out the problem, but the solution different enough to warrant a separate answer:

Open `File Associations` (if plasma search doesn't find it: `System Settings` under `Applications`).

Expand `inode` and find `directory` - type it in the top-left search to filter out the rest:

[image: File Associations screen]

In `Application Preference Order`, select the application you want to use.

If it isn't at the top already, move it up, click `Apply` and see if this fixes things.

Otherwise, click `Edit...`, and open the application tab.

The `Command` field (fourth from the top) is probably not pointing to the actual program, so fix that. **Make sure you keep the `%U` at the end!**

For example, for Dolphin, it should probably look like this:

[image: Edit command path to Dolphin]

If you do not know where your desired application is stored, open a terminal and run `whereis <application>` (it's probably in `/usr/bin/`).

Anyway, that fixed it for me, hopefully this works for others too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when occasionally removed nautilus.

Try`sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus`

Comment: not solved by this :(

Comment: but you have nautilus installed? sudo apt-get install nautilus

Comment: gives `nautilus is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
  webaccounts-extension-common`

Comment: this solution doesn't work with my ubuntu

Comment: also not working here with 21.04